# Bing Maps V8 Web Control geocode accuracy

Tags: javascript, geocoding, bing-maps

Is there any way that the accuracy of geocode search using the V8 web control can be improved? I have around 270 addresses and only around 50 are found (lat / lon). The addresses have been provided by an external source and they lack postal code, coherent format, just street name, some comment (some times), number, city and coutry (all belong to the same city). I know that for REST API, one can increase accuracy providing a user context object. Is there something similar for the web control?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Web SDK simply wraps the REST APIs, so you should see similar results from each. The Web SDK however will use the maps bounding box to provide context for the search since the primary reason for the search module in the web SDK is to use it with the map. You could try setting the bounds option of the geocode request to a bounding box of the full world.

Generally though, you should geocode all addresses ahead of time if you have them. Geocoding them at run time is slow and costly. Geocoding once, storing the results and loading those results when showing the map will be much faster and generate a lot less costs.

When it comes to geocoding, it can only make so much sense out of the input data. If the input is garbage, the output may not be much better.